# seccomp how to handle ptrace events

Tags: c, linux, sandbox, ptrace, seccomp

I am using `seccomp` filters to restrict system calls made by a process. Up to using whitelist of system calls to allow and disallow system call is understandable. I stuck on concept of `ptrace` events generated by `seccomp` rules. For example I can disallow `open` but I want to generate `ptrace` event on `open` system call so that I can determine whether process can open that file or not. My specific question is how to catch ptrace event generated by seccomp? Any help or reference will be a great blessing.

I googled in my humble capacity but did not find any help and running example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate program which traces the inferior. This tracer shall call

```
    ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, tracee_pid, 0, PTRACE_O_TRACESECCOMP);
```

to request notifications, and call

```
    waitpid(tracee_pid, &status, __WALL);
```

to be notified. When `waitpid` returns, analyze `status`, and retrieve notification via

```
    unsigned long data;
    ptrace(PTRACE_GETEVENTMSG, tracee_pid, 0, &data);
```